# How to sum all sheets automatically using excel formua

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have workbook contain multiple worksheets. I want a function which display the autosum of the current worksheet as well as previous not all. For example If I am on the sheet1 it and it has the value in the cell "E12" = 1 then I will write the function =autosum(E12) which will display result in E13 = 1. Then in the sheet2 if the same cell range E12 = 2 and I applied the function "=autosum(e12) it should display on the sheet2 E13 = 3. But when I go back to the sheet1 it should be displayed same as 1 not should display total for all.

I am using this function but it display same total on all the sheet. The function is as under.

```
    Function AutoSum(rng As Range) As Variant
    AutoSum = ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value
    Application.Volatile True
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        If Not WS Is Application.ThisCell.Parent Then
            AutoSum = AutoSum + WS.Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The sheets layout is as under.

[image: Sheet1]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function AutoSum(rng As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim addy As String, ws As Worksheet, wName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    addy = rng.Address
    wName = rng.Parent.Name
    Set wb = rng.Parent.Parent
    AutoSum = 0
    
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(addy)
        If ws.Name = wName Then Exit Function
    Next ws
    
End Function
```

This will sum the given cell from all sheets up to and including the sheet containing the formula.

Answer (score 0):

your all code is correct only sum little changes require.

```
AutoSum = ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value
```

To

```
AutoSum = rng.Value
```

or follow youtube video lin to use  below code

https://youtu.be/4AWt7C2Ugsk

```
Function AutoSum(rng As Range)
Application.Volatile True
For Each WS In Worksheets
        AutoSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(AutoSum, WS.Range(rng.Address))
Next
```

End Function

Comment: Brother my code was working perfect and generating the same result but I am looking for the modification in the code so that each workbook show its tool as well as previous. for example sheet1 should display only its total sheet2 should display its as well as previous total.